# iOS- SQLITE_MISUSE error (code 21)

Tags: ios, database, xcode, sqlite

I try Insert an array of objects into my database , all of them inserted successfully except last one , It give me this error

here is my code I use to insert into database

```
  - (int)insertWithQuery:(NSString *)query {
        sqlite3_stmt *statement;
        const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];

        if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &database) == SQLITE_OK) {
            const char *insert_stmt = [query UTF8String];
            if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, insert_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL)!= SQLITE_OK){

                 NSLog(@"the error occurred here is %s ",sqlite3_errmsg(database));
                return DATABASE_FAILED;

                 }
            int res = sqlite3_step(statement);


            if (res == SQLITE_DONE) {
                return DATABASE_SUCCESS;
            } else if (res == SQLITE_CONSTRAINT) {
                return DATABASE_ALREADY_EXISTS;
            } else {
                return DATABASE_FAILED;
            }
            sqlite3_finalize(statement);
            sqlite3_close(database);
        } else {
            return DATABASE_FAILED;
        }
    }
```

The error Printed to me is

> near "3": syntax error

my Passed query is look like

```
INSERT INTO report (report_id, student_id, report_title, report_body, from_date, to_date, timestamp) VALUES ("217", "1", "", "<h3>Hazem Taha Ghareeb <small>report</small></h3>From: <p>2014-06-17 </p> To: <p>2014-06-24 </p><table><thead><th>Exam</th><th>Date</th><th>Result</th></thead><tbody><tr><td>Java </td><td>2014-06-18 </td><td>138 </td></tr></tbody></table><h3>Absence</h3><table><thead><th>Date</th></thead><tbody><tr><td>2014-06-17 </td></tr><tr><td>2014-06-22 </td></tr><tr><td>2014-06-24 </td></tr></tbody></table></body></html>", "2014-06-17", "2014-06-24", "2014-06-24 12:23:58")
```

The one have problem is

```
INSERT INTO report (report_id, student_id, report_title, report_body, from_date, to_date, timestamp) VALUES ("631", "1", "C class report4", "<h3>Hazem Taha <small>report</small></h3>From: <p>30-01-2015 </p> To: <p>30-01-2015 </p><table><thead><th>Exam</th><th>Date</th><th>Result</th></thead><tbody><tr><td colspan="3"> No exams records. </td></tr></tbody></table><h3>Absence</h3><table><thead><th>Date</th></thead><tbody><tr><td> No absence records. </td></tr></tbody></table></body></html>", "2015-01-30", "2015-01-30", "2015-01-29 08:43:21”)
```

Any one know can help me

Comment: Can you include an example 'query' variable value which results in this error?

Comment: It's a little hard to try and reproduce locally. Do you have a sample project you can upload?

Comment: I will try make one for you now

Comment: @minafawzy: Seems like the issue is with the query you are passing to the sqlite3_prepare

Comment: I working to make this sample , but the passed query is correct you can check it in my question

Comment: @minafawzy: Also never return from that method for finalizing or closing the database. It'll cause issues. Can you share a sample app with the specified issue ?

Comment: I think this part of my query make the problem in report body colspan="3"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70288/discussion-between-mina-fawzy-and-midhun-mp).

Comment: @minafawzy: 
ok, so now you fixed that
Use sqlite3_bind_xxx for binding parameters to the query
Instead of specifying them directly in query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue is you have `"` in your query parameters. You need to escape them with `\"`.

But I would like to suggest using `sqlite3_bind_xxx` methods for binding parameters to your query rather than specifying them in the query statement.
You can read more about it here : [SQLite3 Reference](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/bind_blob.html)

If you open a database connection you should close it. In your code you are returning from many places, so database connection won't be closed properly, it'll cause database locking and other issues.

```
- (int)insertWithQuery:(NSString *)query
{
    int status = DATABASE_FAILED;
    sqlite3_stmt *statement;
    const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];

    if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &database) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
         const char *insert_stmt = [query UTF8String];
         if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, insert_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL)!= SQLITE_OK)
         {
             NSLog(@"the error occurred here is %s ",sqlite3_errmsg(database));
             status = DATABASE_FAILED;
         }
         else
         {
            int res = sqlite3_step(statement);
            if (res == SQLITE_DONE)
            {
                status = DATABASE_SUCCESS;
            }
            else if (res == SQLITE_CONSTRAINT)
            {
                status = DATABASE_ALREADY_EXISTS;
            }
            else
            {
                status = DATABASE_FAILED;
            }
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
        sqlite3_close(database);
    }
 }
```

Comment: Is it not enough close db in `applicationWillTerminate`?

Comment: sqlite3_open and sqlite3_close should be in a 1:1 relation. If you are opening it in a single time in your application life-cycle you only need to close it only once (When you no longer need the db). But I will say that keeping your database connection as open through out the life cycle of your app will not be a good idea. A good approach will be open your db whenever you need, do processing on your db, close the db if you no longer need that.

Answer (score 1):

If you will look on "2015-01-29 08:43:21”, you will notice that you have an incorrect quote `”` which will cause the problem.

So right query will be

```
INSERT INTO report (report_id, student_id, report_title, report_body, from_date, to_date, timestamp) VALUES ("631", "1", "C class report4", "<h3>Hazem Taha <small>report</small></h3>From: <p>30-01-2015 </p> To: <p>30-01-2015 </p><table><thead><th>Exam</th><th>Date</th><th>Result</th></thead><tbody><tr><td colspan="3"> No exams records. </td></tr></tbody></table><h3>Absence</h3><table><thead><th>Date</th></thead><tbody><tr><td> No absence records. </td></tr></tbody></table></body></html>", "2015-01-30", "2015-01-30", "2015-01-29 08:43:21")
```

Comment: I think this part of query make this error <td colspan="3"> No exams records.